# Debugging NameError: name 'QgsLinearlyInterpolateDiagramRenderer' is not defined from PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, nameerror

I have gone through an online tutorial on how to do a pie chart map using PYQGIS.

The following is my code, identical to what was provided.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4.QtGui import*
from PyQt4.QtCore import*
layer = QgsVectorLayer("C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\pygis\County10PopnHou\County10PopnHou.shp","Population","ogr")
categories = [u'PCT_WHT',u'PCT_BLK',u'PCT_AMIND',u'PCT_ASIAN',u'PCT_HAW',u'PCT_ORA',u'PCT_MR',u'PCT_HISP']
colors = ['#3727fa','#01daae','#f849a6','#268605','#6810ff','#453990','#630f2f','#07dd45']
qcolors = map(QColor,colors)
diagram = QgsPieDiagram()
ds = QgsDiagramSettings()
ds.font = QFont("Helvectica", 12)
ds.transparency = 0
ds.categoryColors = qcolors
ds.categoryAttributes = categories
ds.size = QSizeF(100.0,100.0)
ds.sizeType = 0
ds.labelPlacementMethod = 1
ds.scaleByArea = True
ds.minimumSize = 0
ds.BackgroundColor = QColor(255,255,255,0)
ds.penWidth = 0
dr = QgsLinearlyInterpolateDiagramRenderer()
dr.setLowerValue(0.0)
dr.setLowerSize(QSizeF(0.0,0.0))
dr.setUpperValue(2000000)
dr.setUpperSize(QSizeF(40,40))
dr.setClassificationAttribute(6)
dr.setDiagram(diagram)
layer.setDiagramRenderer(dr)
dls = QgsDiagramLayerSettings()
dls.dist = 0
dls.priority = 0
dls.xPosColumn = -1
dls.yPosColumn = -1
dls.placement = 0
layer.setDiagramLayerSettings(dls)
label = QgsPalLayerSettings()
label.readFromLayer(layer)
label.enabled = True
label.writeToLayer(layer)
if hasattr(layer,"setCacheImage"):
    layer.setCacheImage(None)
layer.triggerRepaint()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Upon running on QGIS using the Python console, I get this error.

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/pygis/UsingPieChartSymbols.py", line 21, in 
    dr = QgsLinearlyInterpolateDiagramRenderer()
NameError: name 'QgsLinearlyInterpolateDiagramRenderer' is not defined**

I have no idea why this is occuring and what is missing.

Comment: Correct name for class is **QgsLinearlyInterpolatedDiagramRenderer**. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excluding whatever another error, I found out that **QgsLinearlyInterpolateDiagramRenderer** class does not exist. Correct name for class is **QgsLinearlyInterpolatedDiagramRenderer**. So, your code (with my path to shapefile) can be write as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4.QtGui import*
from PyQt4.QtCore import*
path = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/County10PopnHou/County10PopnHou/County10PopnHou.shp"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(path,"Population","ogr")
categories = [u'PCT_WHT',u'PCT_BLK',u'PCT_AMIND',u'PCT_ASIAN',u'PCT_HAW',u'PCT_ORA',u'PCT_MR',u'PCT_HISP']
colors = ['#3727fa','#01daae','#f849a6','#268605','#6810ff','#453990','#630f2f','#07dd45']
qcolors = map(QColor,colors)
diagram = QgsPieDiagram()
ds = QgsDiagramSettings()
ds.font = QFont("Helvectica", 12)
ds.transparency = 0
ds.categoryColors = qcolors
ds.categoryAttributes = categories
ds.size = QSizeF(100.0,100.0)
ds.sizeType = 0
ds.labelPlacementMethod = 1
ds.scaleByArea = True
ds.minimumSize = 0
ds.BackgroundColor = QColor(255,255,255,0)
ds.penWidth = 0
dr = QgsLinearlyInterpolatedDiagramRenderer()
dr.setLowerValue(0.0)
dr.setLowerSize(QSizeF(0.0,0.0))
dr.setUpperValue(2000000)
dr.setUpperSize(QSizeF(40,40))
dr.setClassificationAttribute(6)
dr.setDiagram(diagram)
layer.setDiagramRenderer(dr)
dls = QgsDiagramLayerSettings()
dls.dist = 0
dls.priority = 0
dls.xPosColumn = -1
dls.yPosColumn = -1
dls.placement = 0
layer.setDiagramLayerSettings(dls)
label = QgsPalLayerSettings()
label.readFromLayer(layer)
label.enabled = True
label.writeToLayer(layer)
if hasattr(layer,"setCacheImage"):
    layer.setCacheImage(None)
layer.triggerRepaint()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

After running it at Python Console of QGIS, I got:

[image]

It can be observed that pie diagrams are not produced as expected. So, there are other issues must be solved.

**Editing Note:**

Above code does not have some lines (see original here: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/QGIS-Python-Programming-Cookbook-Second-Edition/blob/master/Chapter05/B06246_05_21-pie.py). After putting them at following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4.QtGui import*
from PyQt4.QtCore import*

layer = QgsVectorLayer("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/County10PopnHou/County10PopnHou/County10PopnHou.shp","Population","ogr")

categories = [u'PCT_WHT',u'PCT_BLK',u'PCT_AMIND',u'PCT_ASIAN',u'PCT_HAW',u'PCT_ORA',u'PCT_MR',u'PCT_HISP']

colors = ['#3727fa','#01daae','#f849a6','#268605','#6810ff','#453990','#630f2f','#07dd45']

qcolors = map(QColor,colors)

diagram = QgsPieDiagram()  

ds = QgsDiagramSettings()
ds.font = QFont("Helvetica", 12)
ds.transparency = 0 
ds.categoryColors = qcolors
ds.categoryAttributes = categories
ds.categoryLabels = categories
ds.size = QSizeF(100.0,100.0)
ds.sizeType = 0
ds.labelPlacementMethod = 1
ds.scaleByArea = True
ds.minimumSize = 0
ds.BackgroundColor = QColor(255,255,255,0)
ds.PenColor = QColor("black") 
ds.penWidth = 0    

dr = QgsLinearlyInterpolatedDiagramRenderer()
dr.setLowerValue(0.0)
dr.setLowerSize(QSizeF(0.0,0.0))
dr.setUpperValue(2000000)
dr.setUpperSize(QSizeF(40,40))
dr.setClassificationAttribute(6)
dr.setDiagram(diagram)
dr.setDiagramSettings(ds)
layer.setDiagramRenderer(dr)    

dls = QgsDiagramLayerSettings()
dls.dist = 0
dls.priority = 0
dls.xPosColumn = -1
dls.yPosColumn = -1
dls.placement = 0
layer.setDiagramLayerSettings(dls)   

label = QgsPalLayerSettings()
label.readFromLayer(layer)
label.enabled = True
label.writeToLayer(layer)      

if hasattr(layer,"setCacheImage"):
    layer.setCacheImage(None)

layer.triggerRepaint()

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

it produces desired result after running it at Python Console of QGIS:

[image]